# Union types & duck-typing in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that should be able to accept one argument that is either `typeA` or `typeB`.  The two types have some different properties and I need to perform operations using those properties - depending on which type it is.

I am passing a union type to the function's `input`: `typeA | typeB`. But even checking for the unique properties doesn't do the trick. I get the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'typeA | typeB'. Property 'value' does not exist on type 'typeB'.(2339)`

code:

```
interface typeA {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
interface typeB {
  name: string;
  data: number;
};

function double(input: typeA | typeB): number {
  if (input.value) {
    return input.value * 2;
  }
  if (input.data) {
    return input.data * 2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(The same code in typescript playground here: [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjATwA4QILIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpAbnADYCuNMnwoAjaOyIBfYqEixEKdFgBC+DmUqCGTEG3UATOGDi0QwsVAmSJxGHxAIwwAPYhk+53xE8IAClAYfGC0SjjIAD6omBDKAJSm5tBqJMjAMMj+IIFgAHTc-BCxyaSkUBBgfFBuAUF5vALIAFTIAEwSpNIpaRk1uYbGRYQppeWV1Vm1-XBNre3InSMVVcgADFZAA))

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: You can test `if('value' in input)` - this also won't have unexpected behaviour when the value exists but is zero. But you also have a problem because an object like `{name: 'foo': value: 'bar', data: 6}` is assignable to your union because it's assignable to `typeB`. I suggest avoiding non-discriminated unions like this; have a property to label each object with which branch of the union it is, and use that property to do such tests.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks! I hadn't spotted the problem with having both value & data. Adding a literal type property to both interfaces does what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
if ('value' in input) {
  return input.value * 2;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=4&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjATwA4QILIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpAbnADYCuNMnwoAjaOyIBfYqEixEKdFgBC%20DmUqCGTEG3UATOGDi0QwsVAmSJxGHxAIwwAPYhk%2053xE8IAClAYfGC0SjjIAD6omBDKAJSm5tBqJMjAMMi%20AOTc-BCZqW4BQbHJpKRQEGB8UIUggWAAdDkCyABUyABMEqTSKRVVNQX1DYbGbZ1WQA)